# Using System.Windows.DragDrop.DoDragDrop() with touch events?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, drag-and-drop, touch-event

I currently develop an application providing the possibility to drag&drop items from one ListBox to an other. This is working perfectly while using a mouse.

However, when trying to do the same with a touch screen (producing genuine touch events) this will not work.

In my logs I see that the TouchDown and Move is actually detected. But the call to System.Windows.DragDrop.DoDragDrop() does not block as it is the case during mouse usage. It immediately returns, so the drag gesture ends right after it started.

I assume that DragDrop.DoDragDrop() is geared for mouse usage only and depends on a MouseButtonDown during the complete process of dragging?!

So, is there an equivalent for using drag&drop with touch events?

Thanks for any hints

Comment: Apparently my code produces same exception.

Answer (score 1):

OK, sorry.
This is one of these questions which you are able to answer yourself... after some time.
And it even was not related to drag&drop itself.

Just this much:
Drag&Drop was working fine with touch. However, WPF swallowed an exception which occurred while determining a visual for dragging within an adorner. This logic had to be adjusted for touch events...