# Touch DragDrop - Blocks all inputchanges

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop, touch

I'm trying to handle a touch drag and drop operation with `DragDrop.DoDragDrop`. As I read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401768/touch-dragdrop-in-wpf) (I, too, can't use the surface drag framework for this) I also have to implement a `QueryContinueDragHandler`, which I have with the following implementation:

(in the mainwindow constructor)

```
this.QueryContinueDrag += (obj, e) => 
{
    if(_touchDevice.IsActive)
        e.Action = DragAction.Continue;
    else
        e.Action = DragAction.Drop;
};
```

(on some TouchDown Eventhandler)

```
Object data = new Object();
_touchDevice = e.TouchDevice;
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, data, DragDropEffects.Link);
```

However, with this the drag action never ends, as `_touchDevice.IsActive` will always be true, no matter if the TouchDevice is actually still "touching". 
[This question is also related to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467200/using-system-windows-dragdrop-dodragdrop-with-touch-events), but I find the answer unsatisfactory and I didn't want to turn the thread into a zombie.

How can I detect when/if the TouchDevice will be inactive?